# Add KML or URL Map to iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3, mapkit, kml

I'm trying to overlay a custom drawing of a roadway design (kml or dgn) to a map view in my iPhone app using Apple's sample KMLViewer. I can tell it's reading the KML because the map zooms to the bounds of the drawing and a couple fragments of the drawing are displayed as they should be. The big hang up here is most of the drawing does not display at all. The attached screen shot shows just two lines of the drawing being displayed.

[image]

Also, please review the debug log here:

> 2013-07-25 23:07:06.597 KMLViewer[2407:c07] Application windows are
>   expected to have a root view controller at the end of application
>   launch Jul 25 23:07:06 Michaels-iMac.local KMLViewer[2407] :
>   ImageIO: CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData ***
>   CGImageReadSessionGetCachedImageBlockData: readSession [0x8434040] has
>   bad readRef [0x8463610]

I've done a lot of research and this seems to be a hot topic. Can I adapt the KMLViewer to my KML or is there a better Apple method? I'd greatly appreciate some advice. The more specific the better. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow, please read this: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) for the display and [Simple KML](https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML/) for the parsing into native Cocoa types. They as mentioned above you want to use annotations and their views/layers provided by the map view delegate.

Another approach, if this is a static map, is to use [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) to render the KML into a set of tiles that you could overlay onto your regular map.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay but I've been working on it. I successfully created a tilelayer in TileMill and displayed it on a MapBox map. Aside from a few limitations with Mapbox this worked as desired. The one limitation, which is a big one for me, is that the Mapbox satellite base map can't be viewed at high zoom levels so I lose my base map when I zoom in to view the details of my overlay. At this point, MapBox works but until they add higher zoom level capabilities, it won't do exactly what I want it to do. Great suggestion, very close to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have only read around this subject since I've never actually had the need to draw my own routes inside an MKMapView but...

MKPolyLine, a MapKit class and the MKMapViewDelegate protocol method `mapView:(MKMapView *) viewForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)` will be the the way to a solution.

Apple's documentation on [MKPolyLine](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [mapView:viewForOverlay:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:viewForOverlay:)

[An example project](http://navarra.ca/?p=786)

A quick example, showcasing a common [pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911534/how-to-draw-a-mkpolyline-on-a-mapview?rq=1) when learning to draw MKPolyLines

**Edit**

`23:07:06.597 KMLViewer[2407:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

is because you haven't explicitly told Xcode which view controller is the beginning view controller.

You either need to replace `[window addSubview:[someController view]];` to

```
[self.window setRootViewController:someController];
```

in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

or make sure your main.m specifies the proper delegate

```
retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

or (for storyboards) set your storyboard as the main storyboard in Build Settings

Comment: After doing some research here, I believe that I will need to use the Apple KMLViewer or MapBox as incanus suggested. I'm putting a kml map on the map, not just a route so I'll need more than polyline capabilities. Thank you for your response.