# How to trace users location on MKMapview and draw line on users path

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I would like to trace my users path on mapView when the user clicks a button on the map and draw a blue or red line along the path like shown in the image below. Also I would like to measure the distance traveled by the user. Currently I am using MKMapView. Is this task possible with iOS map kit or should i move on to using Google maps SDK. I've just started learning iOS development please bear with me if you find the question out of order. [image] Thanks in advance...;)

Comment: What research have you done into drawing lines on the map?

Comment: I checked some places they suggested me to use MKPolyline method something....Im just not sure about it. I too found some old tutorials but I dont know if they ll work on iOS7...

Comment: iOS7 deprecates some things, but it depends what version on iOS you're supporting. Check MKPolylineView and MKPolylineRenderer too.

Comment: If you don't mind can you help me with some examples...?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911534/how-to-draw-a-mkpolyline-on-a-mapview

Comment: I just checked the above link but this would keep accessing the user's current location won't this lack in battery efficiency..??

Comment: You can get the points to create the line however you want. Take it as a source of inspiration, not a copy-boasted solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit too late, but for the sake of relevance, here's @Rinju's code in Swift (I added a bit more information here too):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
//This is a dummy location, you'd add locations to it using the 
//  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
let location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 200, longitude: 100)
let locationArray:Array<CLLocation> = [location]
let camera:GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (locationArray.first?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (locationArray.first?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 2)
//You can obtain the Lat and Long for above from the list of arrays of locations you saved
//You can use the .first or .last on the array (I used first)

let mapview:GMSMapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

let path:GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()
for nextLocation in locationArray {
    if locationArray.index(of: nextLocation) != 0 {
        //You dont want to use the first one as you've already done it
        //so you start with 1
        path.addLatitude(nextLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: nextLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }
}

let polyline:GMSPolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
polyline.strokeWidth = 2
polyline.map = mapview
self.view = mapview

//I personally prefer view.addSubview(mapview)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`google ios sdk` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/ Follow this.

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "DemoViewController.h"

@implementation DemoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0
                                                          longitude:-165
                                                               zoom:2];
  GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

  GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
  [path addLatitude:-33.866 longitude:151.195]; // Sydney
  [path addLatitude:-18.142 longitude:178.431]; // Fiji
  [path addLatitude:21.291 longitude:-157.821]; // Hawaii
  [path addLatitude:37.423 longitude:-122.091]; // Mountain View

  GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
  polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
  polyline.map = mapView;

  self.view = mapView;
}

@end
```